# Drupal commerce - purchase a product at registration

Tags: commerce, rules, entities

I'm trying to use Drupal Commerce for a subscription site that will have only one product to purchase - a subscription to a service.

I'd prefer if a user could either do product subscription as a part of user registration, or immediately be redirected. Currently I'm trying the redirection with a rule to a custom order page (which I'm creating with rules), however rules doesn't seem to know what the order id is of the created entity.

So I'm either looking for a way to fix that, or another solution that I may have missed. Basically I want registration to be the easiest thing possible.

Answer (score 0):

Figured this out - apparently you have to add the action, "save entity" after you create it, and also force it to save immediately.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it easily by pro-grammatically to implement this functionality. As i already used this earlier.

You just need to use the `hook_form_alter()` drupal function to alter the registration form

```
function regform_form_alter(&$form, $form_state, $form_id) {

if ($form_id == 'Your_FORM_ID') {
$form['#submit'][]='registration_formalter_submit';

}

}
function registration_formalter_submit($form, &$form_state){
 global $user;
 $PID = 2; // say any
  $uid = ($user->uid) ? $user->uid : 0;
    $order = commerce_order_new($uid, 'checkout_checkout');

// Save the order to get its ID.
    commerce_order_save($order);

// Load whatever product represents the item the customer will be
// paying for and create a line item for it.
// here you need to pass product ID
    $product = commerce_product_load($PID);

    $line_item = commerce_product_line_item_new($product, 1, $order->order_id);
// Save the line item to get its ID.
    commerce_line_item_save($line_item);
// Add the line item to the order using fago's rockin' wrapper.
    $order_wrapper = entity_metadata_wrapper('commerce_order', $order);
    $order_wrapper->commerce_line_items[] = $line_item;

// Save the order again to update its line item reference field.
    commerce_order_save($order);
    drupal_goto('checkout');

}
```

Also, add a rule to clear cart before adding a product to a cart.

Hope it works for you!

Comment: Does this work pretty seamlessly? Do you need to have "Add to Cart" enabled? I don't really want to have a cart if at all possible - there's only one product.

I'll take a look at tossing this code in and seeing if it does what I need.

Comment: Yes. It is the appropriate way to purchase a product on registration progrmmatically. Also, you can try a drupal module https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce_registration.